# Find text in File, Copy and Paste in Cells Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, visual-studio-macros

I am writing a code in VBA to look into a file for a characters that the unser inputs in the macro, after the macro finds the characters provided by the user I want it to extract that whole line and past it in a sheet in excel by taking the first characters and placing them in cell 1a then taking the next set of characters which are seperated by a space in the text and placing them into another cell, here is what I have so far and want to replace line 17 with the extraction of data;

```
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim arrData() As String

    Sub test()
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim IngLine As Long
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim bInFound As Boolean
    f = FreeFile
    Tfile = "C:\TAXETI.TXT"
    staffdat = InputBox(Prompt:=" Please enter the staff number", Title:="Load Staff Data")
         Open Tfile For Input As #f
             Do While Not EOF(f)
                  IngLine = IngLine + 1
                  Line Input #f, strLine
                  If InStr(1, strLine, staffdat, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
                     MsgBox "Search string found in line" & IngLine, vbInformation
                     bInFound = True
                     Exit Do
                  End If
             Loop
             Close #f
             If Not bInFound Then
             MsgBox "Search string not found", vbInformation
             End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look into the Split() function.

[MSDN Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx&ei=HKqgUsH3EIegkAef9YGQBg&usg=AFQjCNHE2zXVUrkpNu_ET5srwVYj2TN06Q&bvm=bv.57155469,d.eW0)

[Another example](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/splitondelimiters.aspx)

I Think your code would end up like the following in #17(You would have to either trim/determine where to 'tokenize' your line, depending what your input file looks like):

```
If InStr(1, strLine, staffdat, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
 foundArr = Split(strLine, " ")'change " " to whatever fits your needs
 For i = LBound(foundArr) to UBound(foundArr)
    'enter each string into a cell, etc
 Next i
```

Comment: No problem! Seems like you already had most of the problem solved.

Comment: Hey Max, how about if once instr function finds the character I want it to go 3 lines down and do the mid() function, what would I use for this?

Comment: Hi @AlfredoA., you can use the same method you are using to read in lines `Line Input #f, strLine` to "read" in the next 3 lines when you find your character - thus going down the way you wanted to. However be aware you may find your character less than 3 lines down to the end of your file, so you may need to do error trapping for this scenario. Also, you may want to look into [FileSystemObject](http://ss64.com/vb/filesystemobject.html) for files I/O, I find it much easier.